# Mapping GPS Location after pending intent

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I want to map the loaction from the location poller after the location is found using a broadcast receiver. I can't find any examples demonstrating this. What needs to happen after the onReceive method is executed and the location is found?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you would call `startActivity()` on something that can map those coordinates. Whether that is your own activity or a built-in one (e.g., via a `geo:` `Uri`) is up to you. If it is yours, you would need to arrange to send the latitude and longitude to your activity, such as via `Intent` extras.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I created the pending intent to a broadcast receiver in the onCreate method of a MapActivity. In the onReceive method of the broadcast receiver I get the GPS location. My question is that once I get the GPS locations what do I do to update the map overlay for the GPS location each time a new location is found?

Comment: @JustinFitzgerald: Why are you bothering with `LocationPoller`, then? The complete and entire purpose behind `LocationPoller` is to get locations when you do not have a UI, such as on a scheduled basis. Just use `LocationManager` and `requestLocationUpdates()`.